# Shell script getting superuser privilege without being run as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, sudo

Here is my script:

**script.sh**:

```
sudo cat /etc/passwd-
```

If I am in a `sudo` session (e.g I ran an other command with `sudo` a few minutes ago), and now run

```
script.sh
```

The script will get `sudo` access. However if I run `cat /etc/passwd-/`, I will get a permission denied error.

As a user, I wouldn't expect script.sh to be able to get super user privileges so simply (e.g without me giving access to superuser privileges with `sudo script.sh`).

Is this expected behavior ?
Is it configurable ?

I see that behavior as being completely similar to `sudo su`, e,g potentially giving superuser access to any script you run in that session, but even worse, because you might not even be aware of it, and don't know when it ends (at least not without checking manually)

Comment: Your session has the credentials cached. When you run the script as yourself they are still cached. Run the script in a separate session to avoid that and you can tweak the caching length too (also limit what you can do with `sudo` instead of "everything").

Comment: if all scripts can ask for the credentials, what's the point of using sudo versus a superuser session regarding security ? Would you create a special user to run non-sudo scripts when the credentials are cached ?

Comment: `sudo` is much more configurable than simply allowing a user to become the superuser; restricting a user to only certain privileged commands, either with or without a password.

Comment: Treat a session that you ran `sudo` from like a `su` session and you'll be safer (don't do other things from there, limit the scope of access, etc.). You might be able to force expire the cache, etc. Look at the `sudo` configuration. You can do a lot with it.

Comment: You can change how log it caches your credentials with [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Password_cache_timeout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this expected behaviour ?

Yes, indeed, it is expected behavior. User's cached credential for sudo is responsible for it.

> Is it configurable?

Yes, it is configurable.

And I think your security concern is a valid one. Running `script.sh` in a terminal where a `sudo` command is run before (within a certain timeout), will give the script superuser privilege if the script is written with explicit `sudo` commands.

You can avoid any script not prompting for a password when run as sudo by running it with:

```
sudo -k script.sh
```

It will ask for a password regardless of any previous sudo command/s or session.

> And to run script.sh without sudo i.e with just `script.sh` and still prompt
>   for a password for the sudo command/s:

**You can change the timeout value (the duration sudo maintains the session) permanently:**

run `sudo visudo`

Then change the line:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

To

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0
```

Save and exit (ctrl+X then Y)

This will ensure that sudo asks for a password every time it is run.

**Or If you don't want to change it permanently and want your script to prompt for password at least once (while maintaining a session), then you can change your script like this:**

```
sudo -k first-command-with-sudo
sudo second-command
sudo third
and so on
```

This script will prompt for password at least once regardless of any previous sudo command/s or session.

**In case you are unaware of (or don't have access to) the content of the script script.sh (it can have sudo commands inside it or not)**

And you want to be sure that any sudo command will surely prompt for password at least once, then run `sudo -K` (capital K) before running the script.

Now if you run `script.sh` and if it contains a sudo command, it will surely prompt for password.